# spark skew data aggregation base on gropBy taking more time

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-2.4.5 version & java1.8 in my project.
I have do few aggregations based on some group by columns. Which is resulting a lot of skewness.

In my original data set I need to do aggregations on companies data based on county wise group-by  data.

For similar use-case I have simple and sample dataset below.

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize( 1 to 10000000).map(x => (x/100000.0)).toDF("score")
          .withColumn("country",lit("USA"))

val df2 = sc.parallelize( 1 to 100).map(x => (x/1000.0)).toDF("score")
          .withColumn("country",lit("AUS"))

val df = df1.unionByName(df2)
df.show()


val viewName = "tabl";
df.createOrReplaceTempView(viewName);

val query = "select country, percentile(score,0.0) as percentile_0 ,avg(score) as mean , count(1) as cnt from  tabl group by country "
val ben = spark.sql(query);
spark.catalog.dropTempView(viewName);
ben.show(2)
```

[image]

Comment: @Raphael Roth Can you please help me how to solved the above skew data.

Comment: @Shaido can you please tell me how to handle groupBy of skewed data ?

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski how to handle groupBy of skewed data ?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#approx_percentile

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz how does this solve the problem of skewness

Comment: Yes. The execution time drops to the floor.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz so how to improve it ? how to avoid skewness ?

Comment: Use approx_percentile instead of percentile

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz thats not giving the correct value. hence I am forced to use "percentile" instead of "approx_percentile"

Comment: (1) "approx" is a shortcut for "approximate" (2) you can tune the error rate

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Even if I tune error rate how can I avoid skewness ? as i am using groupBy ...how to handle it ?

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz sorry for delay ... yes i tested its not giving exact results.

Comment: (1) Performance wise you should have seen a massive improvement (2) As I said, "approx" is a shortcut for "approximate" and you can tune the error rate

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz  , any clue on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035832/exception-occured-while-writing-delta-format-in-aws-s3 ?