# Exception occured while writing delta format in AWS S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I am using spark 3.x, java8 and delta 1.0.0 i.e. delta-core_2.12_1.0.0 in my spark job.
data is persisted in AWS S3 path in "delta" format of parquet.

**Below are details of Jars I am using in my spark job.**

spark-submit.sh

```
export SPARK_HOME=/local/apps/pkg/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.9.1-custom
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.0.2,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0
```

pom.xml

```
<spark.version>3.0.2</spark.version>
```

**While saving bigger set of data job failing to write data with below error**

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.write(WriteIntoDelta.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1(WriteIntoDelta.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(WriteIntoDelta.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.run(WriteIntoDelta.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:962)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:962)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:287)
        at com.spgmi.ca.benchmark.datasource.DeltaDataSource.write(DeltaDataSource.java:47)
        ... 8 more

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 67 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1(DAGScheduler.scala:979)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:977)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:977)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:2257)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2170)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:1988)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1357)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1988)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$35(SparkContext.scala:638)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1934)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:200)
```

So what is wrong here ?
how to debug and fix this issue ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I know like to know more about: 1.what is your driver and executor configuration? 2. what is the size of your data? 3. How to you run your spark application (AWS EMR/Yarn/k8s/...)? Based on the traceback you provided, I suspect that your `sc` was stopped due to memory overhead, either caused by insufficient memory or data skew. Another reason might be version conflict between your `spark` and `delta lake`. Based on my understanding, delta version `1.0.x` required spark version `3.1.x`, make sure that the version is aligned.

Comment: Are you trying to run spark locally?
Try adding delta-storage-1.x.x.jar based on your spark delta version.

Comment: And when you say "While saving bigger set of data job failing to write data with below error" does it mean it works when you are writing the small datasets? 


If that is the case, check for the entire log for more details. Plus make sure the same path is not getting updated from other job while you are updating.(due to https://docs.delta.io/latest/concurrency-control.html )

Comment: @Ajith, yes for smaller set of data it is writing. for larget set it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Delta version that is incompatible with your Spark. The last version of Delta working with Spark 2.4 was version 0.6.x (0.6.2 as I remember, although I didn't check).  See the [versions compatibility matrix](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html) for more information.

P.S. It really makes no sense to use Spark 2.4 in 2022nd - Spark 3.0+  has a lot of optimizations compared to 2.x...

Comment: yes I have 3.x spark version , please check "Below are details of Jars I am using in my spark job." section of the question.